# Best way to implement file name version in apache

Tags: php, html, apache, proxy, browser-cache

I was reading that it is better to name my file "test.v01.css" instead of "test.css?v=01" because of some proxies that ignore the CGI-param part.

The question is:

What is the easiest way to do that?
(for all files ending with ".js" & ".css")

I'm using PHP & Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s # Make the file doesn't actually exist
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]+\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L] # Strip out the version number
```

php:

```
function versioning($file)
{
  if(strpos($file, '/') !== 0 || !file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file))
    return $file;

  $mtime = filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file);
  return preg_replace('{\\.([^./]+)$}', ".$mtime.\$1", $file);
}
```

usage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=versioning('/stylesheet/base.css')?>" type="text/css" />
```

results:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet/base.94857365432.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the end-to-end solution!